# LaunchDaemon exits immediately, but keeps running when I run it directly

Tags: macos, daemon, launchd

I have never written a LaunchDaemon before, so I'm starting with a dead-simple one.  Even my simple one does not appear to execute.

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

EDIT: My system.log is full of the following:

```
Dec  6 00:02:47 Michaels-Mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.frescologic.hello): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec  6 00:02:57 Michaels-Mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.frescologic.hello[1386]): Service could not initialize: 16F73: xpcproxy + 11769 [1505][34964CF1-9965-3B4D-ADC7-6FBC6669C56D]: 0x2
```

However when I run hello directly from the command line, it keeps running.

My configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.frescologic.hello</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

My daemon's source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *outFile;

    if ( argc != 2 ){

        fprintf( stderr, "Usage:\n $ %s world\n", argv[ 0 ] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    outFile = fopen( "/tmp/foo", "w" );
    if ( outFile == NULL ) exit( 1 );

    while ( 1 ){
        fprintf( outFile, "%s\n", argv[ 1 ] );
        sleep( 10 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The relevant permissions:

```
$ ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.frescologic.hello.plist 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  375 Dec  5 21:47 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.frescologic.hello.plist
```

and

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/libexec
total 40
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18240 Dec  5 21:45 hello
```

Launchctl claims it's running:

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep hello
Password:
-   78  com.frescologic.hello
```

But ps does not:

```
$ ps -ef | grep hello
  501   737   387   0 10:38PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep hello
```

and

```
$ ps -ax | grep hello
  743 ttys000    0:00.00 grep hello
```

The log file does not exist:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ls
com.apple.launchd.JOJDWGHX78    com.apple.launchd.oUj51Uvj6v
```

Help Me O-Stackoverflow You're My Only Hope!

Answer (score 0):

Stephàne answered this on darwin-drivers@lists.apple.com.  Add the "Program" key to the property list with the full path of the executable:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/local/libexec/hello</string>
```